# A proper way to pass log prefix with multiple shared libraries in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, shared-libraries

The question is actually more general, but it is more clear on the example of logging.

1. **Project hierarchy**

```
HelpersLib -> Shared libA
           |
           -> Shared libB
           ... more shared libs
```

- `HelpersLib` - static lib, hold some base functional for all shared
- `libA`, `libB` - independent shared libs (dll/so)

Finally, I have an application that dynamically loads all `libA`, `libB`, etc. and uses them all.

2. **Classes**

To be more specific:

- `HelpersLib` has class `Ping` and method `Start`
- `libA` has class `CheckA`, that use `Ping::Start` inside
- `libB` has class `CheckB`, that use `Ping::Start` inside

3. **Logging**

All classes use logging inside (log frameworks does not matter for now) with macros looks like this:

```
//HelpersLib

#define HELPERS_INFO(prefix, ...) LOG(prefix, loglevel::info ...)
#define HELPERS_WARN(prefix, ...) LOG(prefix, loglevel::warn ...)
...

//libA
#define LIBA_INFO(prefix, ...) LOG(prefix, loglevel::info ...)
#define LIBA_WARN(prefix, ...) LOG(prefix, loglevel::warn ...)

//libB
#define LIBA_INFO(prefix, ...) LOG(prefix, loglevel::info ...)
#define LIBA_WARN(prefix, ...) LOG(prefix, loglevel::warn ...)
```

When app load all shared `libA`, `libB`, etc. and call `CheckA` then `CheckB` i want to see in app log something like this

```
[libAPrefix] Run checking...  <-- enter CheckA
[libAPrefix] pinging...       <-- run Ping::Start inside CheckA
...
[libBPrefix] Run checking...  <-- enter CheckB
[libBPrefix] pinging...       <-- run Ping::Start inside CheckB
...
```

4. **Problem**

So, the main problem is - how to pass correct prefix to `HelpersLib` and make it correct with multiple `HelperLib` instance are load in main app

for now i use external linkage for `prefix` var

```
//HepersLib header
extern const char* prefix  

//LibA header
extern const char* prefix  
//LibA some cpp
const char* prefix = "libAPrefix"

//LibB header
extern const char* prefix  
//LibB some cpp
const char* prefix = "libBPrefix"
```

This is works, but i think it's not a best solution - global external vars always not good idea and under linux this requited `RTLD_LOCAL` for `dlopen()` that not always possible (otherwise HelpresLib::prefix will be initialized only once for first lib and it won't work right for all other shared libs)

Maybe exist more clean and safe solution for set prefix? Maybe someone have tips for reorganize logging code for static + shared libs?

Comment: Learn about dependency inversion and injection. Logging should be totally optional (replacable by a null-strategy) and not be managed through global variables and/or macros (or you will just kill unit testaility).

Comment: Also see : [Lightning Talk: Global API Injection in C++ - Ben Deane - CppNow 2023](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYpcAEfG3mo)

Comment: In other words, concretely, libA would usually pass the logger to the objects or functions from the common lib.